# Importing and Accessing a sqlite Created Database IN FLASK without using SQL_ALCHEMY

Tags: sqlite, flask, cs50

I am generally new to programming, with a large capacity for self-learning. I have found myself, after taking Harvard's CS50 program unable to use a database in FLASK (using python).

I have created the database with sqlite and have it saved to my work environment and a copy in exterior folders.

I would not like to use FLASK ALCHEMY as I am 100% comfortable in SQL and would not like to start defamiliarizing myself with the basic usage.

I am using visual studio and have Flask already properly installed, and being used to define working routes already.

The database is named trial.db and it can be assumed to have been properly set-up.

```
import os


from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, 
session, jsonify
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, 
InternalServerError
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, 
generate_password_hash

from helpers import apology, login_required, lookup, usd

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True



@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must- 
revalidate"
response.headers["Expires"] = 0
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
return response



app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd


app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)


db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
```

** THE ABOVE CODE is what I am use to calling based on CS50s library, which is excessively generous.**

SQL, as above is utilized like such:

cs50.SQL(url)
Parameters
url – a str that indicates database dialect and connection arguments

Returns
a cs50.SQL object that represents a connection to a database

Example usage:

```
db = cs50.SQL("sqlite:///file.db")  # For SQLite, file.db must exist
```

Please help, and Thank you

Comment: I can't speak to CS50 at Harvard, but a quick run through the Flask Mega Tutorial maybe worth your time. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Comment: What do you mean "unable to use"? Is it giving error messages?  Use full path or relative path if database doesn't live in document root (the dir where app.py lives).

Comment: I am able to create a connection to the database using an engine and connection. But executing the raw SQL is proving difficult. And commanding data is difficult. It looks like there is a lot more going on in order to properly facilitate a connection than I assumed. I will follow the above listed tutorial and get back.